# How do I pass a reference to an object via functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, namespaces, reference

I want to do:

```
mkArray(xml, "artist", "namespace.newarray");

function mkArray(xml, tag, store){
    store = [];
    $(xml).find(tag).each(function(i,v){
        store.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(store);
}
```

But of course this overwrites what store is, rather than using it as a reference to a property of namespace. What's the correct way of going about it? I thought window[store] would work, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: In this circumstance, the *correct* way, I would say, would be to return the array from `mkArray` and to assign it; `namespace.newarray = mkArray(xml, "artist")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's better to avoid functions that have side effects, e.g. change their arguments. If your function is supposed to create something, just return this "something":

```
// good way

function mkArray(xml, tag) {
   var store = [];
   // populate store...
   return store;
}

myStore = mkArray(xml, tag);
```

If, for some reason, that doesn't work for you, you can also modify the function argument, but the object itself should be created in the calling code:

```
// worse, but possible 

function mkArray(xml, tag, store) {
   // populate store...
}

myStore = [];
mkArray(xml, tag, myStore);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an object, and pass the object. Then, modify the property of the object:

```
var reference = {store: void 0};   // Or just {};
mkArray(xml, tag, reference);      // <-- Pass the "reference"
console.log(reference.store);      // <--- Yup.

function mkArray(xml, tag, o_store){
    o_store.store = [];
    $(xml).find(tag).each(function(i,v){
        store.push($(this).text());
    });
    // console.log(o_store.store);  // Look ahead
}
```

Comment: I just noticed the slightly edited question. I recommend to have a look at Matts comment. If you want to change your function, without editing the rest of the calls, use: `var storeProps = store.split('.'), store = window;for (var i=0; i<storeProps.length; i++) {store = store[storeProps[i]];}`. Assuming that these properties are globally defined.